# Xcode - Localizable.strings no longer works

Tags: localizable.strings

I've got an iPhone project and my english Localizable.strings suddenly doesn't work anymore. I just noticed the english Localizable.strings file in the resulting .app-folder hardly has any data in it at all. From my 3500 bytes original english file, the one in the .app is 50 bytes (compared with the japanese which is 3000 bytes in the .app).

Where did all the data go?

I've been trying to remove the build folder and rebuilding everything, but that doesn't seem to help. The japanese strings work just fine.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were invisible errors in the english file. Each row started with 0xFFFE, which they supposedly shouldn't do. This was tricky as it didn't show up in any text editor I used. It wasn't until I opened the file in a hex editor that this showed up (not so obvious I might add :p). I used [hex fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) for this.

Comment: Having gone through similar problems, I can recommend MacOS's builtin tool hexdump:

hexdump -C Localizable.strings

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues, in my case they were related to the encoding of the .strings files. Apparently Xcode expects them to be UTF-16, but after editing them in some arbitrary app it appears they were saved as UTF-8.

I solved it by opening them in Xcode, and then via the Utilities bar explicitly setting the encoding to UTF-16.